# Equivalence of norms in $C^1[0,1]$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

i have the following problem/questions:
I have to prove that $\lVert \cdot \rVert_1 \sim \lVert \cdot \rVert_{*}  $ in $C^1[0,1]$;
Where $\lVert \cdot \rVert_1$ is the usual $C^1[0,1]$ norm and $\lVert f \rVert_{*} =\lvert f(0)\rvert + \sup_{t\in[0,1]}\, \lvert f'(t) \rvert $.
It's easy to show that $\lVert f \rVert_1 \geq \lVert f \rVert_{*}  $.
I have have some problem to check the other inequality.
My first idea was to create a functional $T(f)=f(0)+f'(t)$ and to apply in some way the Banach-Steinhaus theorem.
My second idea produces the following question:
if i show that 2 different norms coincide on the norm-null function, are they equivalent?
[$\lVert f \rVert_1 =0] \Rightarrow [\lVert f \rVert_{*}=0]  $ and [$\lVert f \rVert_* =0] \Rightarrow [\lVert f \rVert_{1}=0$] implies that $\lVert \cdot \rVert_1 \sim \lVert \cdot \rVert_{*}  $?
Which idea do you suggest?

Comment: The second idea is wrong, all norms have the same null space, $\{0\}$. You could try the closed graph theorem. Or you could simply write $f(t) = f(0) + \bigl(f(t) - f(0)\bigr)$ to get the domination in the other direction.

Comment: Brilliant! thank you!!!!

Comment: If you mean topologically equivalent, then you would need to prove $\|f\|_1 \le (\text{some positive constant}\cdot\|f\|_*)\vphantom{\frac\int\int}$,  (And "constant" means not depending on which $f\in C^1[0,1]$ it is. ${}\qquad{}$